# Cannot log in to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server after enabling root login for SSH via PermitRootLogin

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login

When trying to log in as root (with public key) to an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box, the OpenSSH server will just say

```
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
```

I have enabled root login by setting `PermitRootLogin` accordingly and have also restarted SSH with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`.

I have also verified that this specific error would not occur if my key were wrong or not in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Why can't I log in ?

*Disclaimer: Yeah, I know that using a root account on Ubuntu is not the proper way to do it, but I was told to. Meh.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem lies with the seemingly innocuous `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`.

Although it does not print any errors, it will simply not restart / reload the server, therefore root login is not yet enabled.

The solution is to just use `service ssh restart`. Duh.

I know that the `/etc/init.d` way is deprecated but as long as it is still supported I'd prefer using it though.

Ubuntu's service script should at least fail rather than do nothing, ah well.

Comment: The script checks to see if it's being run by upstart and exits silently if not - which isn't great.